# how cacn i display select datagridview row using the keyboard Arrow?

Tags: vb.net

i am using VS2022.net

How can I display datagridview values in textboxes?

Move by keyboard arrows

thanks in advance

here is my code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellStateChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellStateChanged
    TxtBook.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
    TxtAuthor.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
    TxtPublisher.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
    TxtPublish.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
    txtPage.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
    TxtNote.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: [DataGridView.SelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) Event. Also, read the Remarks section to determine whether the `CurrentCellChanged` event will be more suitable for you to handle.

Comment: it give me this error
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.CurrentRow.get returned Nothing.

Comment: You need to do `Nothing` check. `IF DataGridView1.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then ..` fill the boxes with the cells values. Otherwise clear them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response
I thank you for your valuable advice
It worked for me

Comment: You have `Option Strict Off`. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454552/what-do-option-strict-and-option-explicit-do) Q&A and the similar ones. Official docs. [Option Strict Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellChanged
    If DataGridView1.CurrentRow IsNot Nothing Then
        TxtBook.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value
        TxtAuthor.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value
        TxtPublisher.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(3).Value
        TxtPublish.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(4).Value
        txtPage.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(5).Value
        TxtNote.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(6).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).